# Joomla 3.0- I cannot get my editor to save an image correctly without it filtering the html?

Tags: text, joomla, filter, image, joomla3.0

I'm making just a regular article and in the editor I want to add an image to the article. When I add it, it works fine but when I go to save the article the html is always filtered. I did my own research on forums and have tried to change the super-user,administrator,etc to no filtering on the text filtering options in global configuration. I've also installed JCE Editor and used that as my default editor and it still filters the img html tags. 
This is what it puts in the img tags

`<img src="\&quot;images/random/my_image.jpg\&quot;">`

If anyone has had this problem and found a solution.

Comment: Are you adding the image using JCE, or with code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

magic quotes was off set to "NO" or get it changed through php.ini or server, if not causes this issue.

Magic quotes is a controversial feature of the PHP scripting language, wherein special characters are prefixed with a backslash before being passed on. It was introduced to help newcomers write functioning SQL commands without requiring manual escaping. ...hence the not saving images

Answer (score 0):

I having the same problem here with joomla 3.0.1 but couldn't find a solution for it, so I just re-installed joomla and everything seems to be working fine now.

I tried different method to get rid of it but no avail all I get to solve this issue when I was re-installing joomla I saw magic quotes was off set to "NO" at installation window so first you should try magic quotes off "YES" if not than check if you can install another joomla for testing if you can install it than re-install your original joomla again with the same database. make sure you export old DB

say hi if it helps you :P